# How do include a parent folder in an SVN repository with Tortoise?

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I have a folder structure like this...

```
/main/project/web-app/versioned
/main/project/web-app/more-versioned
/main/project/web-app/unversioned
```

I mirrored this in my SVN repository without the unversioned folder

```
/main/project/web-app/versioned
/main/project/web-app/more-versioned
```

I checked out into `versioned` and `more-versioned`, but I realised that really I should have checked out into `web-app`, so I checked it out as a top level folder and mapped it to my local `/main/project/web-app` folder.

I expected SVN (or Tortoise which I am using as a client) to figure out that this was a directly mapped parent folder and for me to be able to submit all changed in sub-folders of web-app, however when I try that I get a message saying nothing has changed in `web-app`.

What do I need to do to get SVN and/or Tortoise to map my local web-app folder, and its contents, to the repository, and ignore the unversioned folder?

Comment: So, you did svn checkout web-app to c:\path\web-app, edited some files in web-app working copy, then did an svn commit? Please be more concise on the steps to reproduce

Answer (score 1):

1. Check out `/main/project/web-app`.  This will give you a working copy folder, called `web-app`, that contains `versioned` and `more-versioned`.
2. Drop your `unversioned` folder into this newly created `web-app` folder.
3. Ignore `unversioned` (by setting the `svn:ignore` property on `web-app` to `unversioned`).

Your use of the phrase "check out *into*" makes me think you have pre-existing target folders before you create your working copy.  This should not be the case.  Checking out will create the folder(s) for you.